# Bought a lemon and the bill of sale has an incorrect price

Tags: scams, car, law, ohio

I paid $2100 for a vehicle but on the bill of sale he put $839.75. I paid with card through cash app so I have proof of what I actually paid.

The vehicle got less than a quarter mile down the road and it started smoking and I had to have it towed home.

I called them as soon as I pulled up at the gas station MAYBE a quarter mile down the road and received no answer. I called back the next day and was treated like crap with the guy cutting me off and saying "oh well we can't help you". I was asking if they could provide ANYTHING to help address the towing expense.

It was sold "As is no warranty" but I just want to know if there is some legal action I can take? This seems completely unfair!

Comment: Generally, law questions depend on jurisdiction. So please say what country (and State/province) you're in. Also, whether you bought from a private person or a dealer/trader.

Comment: "I paid 2100 dollars for a vehicle but on the bill of sale he put $839.75." Tax evasion.

Comment: Columbus Ohio, I bought it from the dealership

Comment: How do I pursue the tax evasion they have done?

Comment: Tax evasion is NOT YOUR PROBLEM. You can tell the state revenue department that you have suspicions that this dealer is misreporting sales to avoid taxes, mentioning your experience. But it is up to them do decide whether and how to process from there, and inserting yourself into the process may gum up the legalities much more than it helps. If they don't ask you for more information, let it be.

Answer (score 3):

As @littleadv said in the comments, "In California [and possibly other jurisdictions], buying a used car from a dealership comes with a mandatory cooling off period that cannot be waived." If you are lucky, you live in an area which has such a law, and may be able to use it to demand the dealer take the car back. You may need to be able to quote the specific law and threaten them with lawsuit to get them to comply. Consumer protection groups may be able to help you with this process. Move fast; the cooling off period is generally fairly short.

But "As is, no warranty" means no warranty, as is, buyer beware, you really should get it professionally checked out before paying. If that isn't acceptable, do not agree to those terms; if they insist, shop elsewhere.

You *should* be able to get a correct bill of sale -- again a local consumer protection group may be able to help you get the seller to comply. If not, saving the credit card receipt (and complaining to the local better business bureau or otherwise giving them a bad review to warn future customers) may be the best you can do.

*ADVICE FOR NEXT TIME:*

When considering a used car, even with a warranty or from friends, ALWAYS get a trusted mechanic (not the seller's!) to check it out and tell you what it's likely to need before you sign.  The standard request is "please go over it as if your kid was considering buying it -- would you let them, how much work is it likely to need immediately, and do you think this is a fair price." That inspection will probably cost you a few hundred dollars. But it may save you from a mistake costing much more than that.

If the seller won't let you borrow it long enough to do that, that means they know it isn't worth buying. Again,  look elsewhere.

Never let yourself fall in love with a particular car. There are others. If there's anything odd about the transaction, walk away.

*AFTERTHOUGHT:*

If the dealer insists the receipt is correct, tell the credit card company you were overcharged, present the receipt as evidence, have them correct or reverse the charge pending investigation, and let the dealer argue with the credit card company. Or tell the dealer that, unless you get a correct receipt, this is what you are going to do; I suspect they'll cave pretty quickly.

Comment: In the US, at least in California, buying a used car from a dealership comes with a mandatory cooling off period that cannot be waived

Comment: And most jurisdictions allow you to return goods if they are "not fit for purpose".

Comment: "As is" explicitly disclaims fitness for purpose of immediate use. All it's being sold as fit for is examination and possible repair or parts. Sorry, but _that_ is the purpose the buyer agreed to.

Comment: Cooling off period, if available in your area, us indeed your best bet. I'll copy that into my answer; thanks .

Comment: "as is" I understand. There are still lemon laws, and I was given misleading information . Then the paperwork was falsified with incorrect payment. They never signed my copies and I don't quite remember signing the "copies" of the paperwork they give me